# is it possible to pre-load a playlist from network with android mediaplayer?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I'm working on an app that involves listening to playlists of audio tracks that are loaded asynchronously from network. the issue here is using mediaplayer, i load (prepare) each audio track after the other, which causes a slight delay between playing tracks that i don't want. i was wondering if there is a way to load/prepare the entire list of tracks first and then play them..is there a way to do that?

my current logic is something like this:

```
var currentPlayingIndex = mutableStateOf(0)
val _playList=["url","url","url","url","url","url"]

mediaPlayer.apply {
                reset()
                setDataSource("url to audio")
                prepareAsync()
                setOnPreparedListener {
                    if (_isPlaying.value) {
                        println("current ${currentPlayingIndex.value}")
                        it.start()
                    }
                }
                setOnCompletionListener {
                        currentPlayingIndex.value++
                        playAudio(
                            _playList[currentPlayingIndex.value],
                            context,
                            mediaPlayer
                        )
                    
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can Achieve the Similar effect with the use of `setOnBufferingUpdateListener` and `setOnInfoListener`. In this code when the current track reached around its last 30 seconds, it started buffering next track, once the currect track ended, next track started playing without any Gap. It was called as Gapless playback.

```
var currentPlayingIndex = mutableStateOf(0)
val _playList = listOf("url1", "url2", "url3", "url4", "url5", "url6")
var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

fun prepareAndPlay(index: Int) {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()

    mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(_playList[index])
    mediaPlayer?.prepareAsync()

    mediaPlayer?.setOnPreparedListener {
        if (_isPlaying.value && currentPlayingIndex.value == index) {
            it.start()
        }
    }

    mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener {
        currentPlayingIndex.value++
        if (currentPlayingIndex.value < _playList.size) {
            prepareAndPlay(currentPlayingIndex.value)
        }
    }

    mediaPlayer?.setOnBufferingUpdateListener { _, percent ->
        if (percent >= 95 && mediaPlayer?.duration?.minus(mediaPlayer?.currentPosition ?: 0)!! <= 30000) {
            currentPlayingIndex.value++
            if (currentPlayingIndex.value < _playList.size) {
                prepareAndPlay(currentPlayingIndex.value)
            }
        }
    }
}

fun startPlayback() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
        prepareAndPlay(currentPlayingIndex.value)
    }
}
```

In the above code you can change where do you want to stream your next song, I have added 30000, which was 30 seconds before the end of track. Adjust code as per your requirement.

Comment: Great answer @Sanjay. But this'll fail if the user presses the skip button. What I'll suggest is to cache the next 5-10 (Acc to your requirement) so it plays instantaneously. When playing next song, look for your cache, If it's there, play it otherwise play via url. The cache I'm talking about is temp cache that clears when you close the app.

Comment: Yes, Caching next set of tracks was helpful too. As user can seamlessly switch between tracks, which provides better user experience.